# Is it possible to edit wiki pages with multiple people at the same time?

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible to edit wiki pages with multiple people at the same time?
Is there any official page that refer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to edit with multiple people.

I tried create user A and B. First A edits like "ABCDE", and also B edits like "12345".
Then A hit the save button and it is okay but after A saves the page, B hit the save button and gitlab shows a following message:

`Someone edited the page the same time you did. Please check out the page and make sure your changes will not unintentionally remove theirs.`